# Does hystrix have the capability to recover the pending requests in the queue?

Tags: recovery, hystrix

I enabled Hystrix fallback() method in my service A, so whenever a dependent service B is down, its going to the fall-back method and displays the static message I provided.

While doing this I am also sending the failed request to a mq ( rabbit mq)

Now, how can I retrieve the pending or waiting request in the queue and reprocess it when the dependent service B is up?

Comment: @ahus1 I saw that you have hands on experience with hystrix can you please help me out with this?

Comment: A guess on your question title: did you mean "Does hystrix have the capability to recover the pending requests in the queue?"

Comment: Yes :-) I am able to open the circuit and send the failed requests to the queue, but will the circuit gets  closed and pre process the pending requests once the service is up?

Comment: Yes :-) I am able to open the circuit and send the failed requests to the queue, but will the circuit gets closed and re process the pending requests once the service is up

Comment: changed the title according to the (accepted by the OP) @leanne's suggestion. And fixed some spelling and added some newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Without a full overview of your architecture (which would be beyond scope here) it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve. But at first glance it sounds like you're expecting too much of Hystrix. Once the fallback is complete, it's complete.

If you've sent a message to a Queue, that message needs to be consumed from somewhere. You want the message to be only consumed when Service B is running - so logically the only option is for Service B to consume from this failed requests queue. So presumably on consumption of that message, Service B would need to repeat the request on Service A.

I suppose you could have a watchdog service that on receipt of a message from the failed requests queue, then it starts checking the health of service B and once it's gone "green" reattempts the request on service A.

It all sounds very tangled to me, I would suggest a rethink.

I'm guessing this static message is something like "sorry, we couldn't complete your request now, but we'll try for you in the background".

From that I sense it would be better if you made Service B be purely message driven in the first place. Get Service A to send a message straight to Service B. Then there's no need to worry about the service being down or overloaded or whatever.

Comment: Ok if not the architecture, let me explain you what I am doing, I have two services one is entity service ( verb based service B) and the other is the calling service ( Noun base service A), so here I am making a rest call  from my service A to service B(entity service). Entity service will just take the request from Service A and make a transaction from DB and send it to Service A and display the message or data etc., So now when my service B is down iam able to open the circuit and send the message say "resource uri is down and will be shortly" to mq, will I able to reprocess it once B is up

Comment: Well you've really just restated your question there. As far as I know Hystrix doesn't have the feature you're looking for and it would overcomplicate things anyway. I restate that if you're expecting unreliable amounts of uptime on your Service B, make it a message driven service instead. On success B can notify A and you can update your UI or whatever dynamically.